# Python parser for AMPL data file

Tags: python, optimization, jupyter-notebook, ampl

In many application we need optimization. Usually data on which optimization is required in database or text files. Is there any python parser/utility that reads translate python data structures into AMPL data file so that we can run optimization?

Answer (score 2):

You could try an ad-hoc solution if you only need to convert Python data structures to AMPL data. Try, for example, [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org) to define the specific AMPL format you need.

In the event that you need to convert AMPL data to Python structures, you should try [Amply](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/main/amply.html).

Another approach could be to write your model in Python and run the solver from Python too, without the need to use AMPL. In this case, you should try [Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org) or [PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/index.html).